# Do Rigveda samhita mention himalyas and mount-kailasha?

Tags: vedas, shiva, rig-veda, identification-request

Do Rigveda samhita mention Himalayas? or the Himalayan range? Vedas mention Kailasa as adobe of lord Rudra in Yajurveda but does the Rigveda mention

**1. Himalayas**

**2. Mount Kailasa** (as in Yajurveda it is adobe of lord Rudra, is it same in Rigveda or even mentioned?)

**For mount kailasha if answer is not sufficient other vedas can be cited for refrence**

Comment: Uttarkuru is also one of the possible names. And I am searching for Mt. Kailash also which is probably Meru. Will update ans. as soon as i will find more info. regarding the tropics.

Comment: Why are u looking for this info? Anything special ? :)

Comment: @Rickross not at starting but rigveda and samaveda show many attributes of the oldest which were condenced to them only while many good attributes respect of women,  pure good family relations etc which contined but not survived a lot may be this not complete true but then also it's quite intresting so knowing many things about vedas is a quite natural :-)

Comment: Why do u think Rig Veda and Sama are the oldest? It is said in the Vedas that the Gods were unsatisfied after the creation of Riks and Yajus and that's why Samans were created..@Fiercelord

Answer (score 7):

**Yes** Himalaya and it's ranges are mentioned in [**Rig-Veda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10121.htm)   Samhita. The Himalayas is called "Himavanta" during Vadic Times.

> यस्येमे **हिमवन्तो** महित्वा यस्य समुद्रं रसया सहाहुः | 
>  यस्येमाः
>   परदिशो यस्य बाहू कस्मै देवाय हविषाविधेम || RV 10.121.4
>
> yasyeme **himavanto** mahitvā yasya samudraṃ rasayā sahāhuḥ |
>
> His, through his might, are these **snow-covered mountains**, and men
>   call sea and Rasā his possession: His arms are these, his are these
>   heavenly regions. What God shall we adore with our oblation?

---

According to the book -  [**Vedic Index of Names and Subjects**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=U5GaKHfNzScC&pg=PA503&lpg=PA503&dq=Himalayan%20mountains%20in%20rig%20veda%20samhita&source=bl&ots=momMhexkb8&sig=itTDvxfzhxsgTxHvokrQy6wleSU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN16COlZHZAhUFRo8KHYVyBusQ6AEwEXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Himalayan%20mountains%20in%20rig%20veda%20samhita&f=false) , Volume 2; Volume 5 by
By Arthur Anthony Macdonell, Arthur Berriedale Keith.

This mountain range is what is Himalayan Range.

> There seems no reason to deny that in all the passages the word refers
>   vaguely to the mountains now called Himalaya.

Comment: find for mount kailash meru etc. from rigveda along if you do not get sufficient then can source from other vedas too.

Comment: @Fiercelord - yes i will update the answer from other vedas too. Thanks .

Comment: this may or may not be the himalaya - but it had no influence on rig vedic religion.

Comment: Upanishds also mentioning goddess uma the daughter of Himavat. We can see the gradual development of stories and notions related to Himalaya from this i.e. later Rig-Vedic texts.

Comment: yes - himalaya plays no part in rig vedic religion but becomes important to hinduism proper with the addition of upanishads,itihasas and puranas @swiftpushkar

Comment: Himavat Parvata has always referred to the Himalayas. There is no reason for a modern name to appear in the Vedas. (Mount Everest will not be called so in the Vedas :) ). The Himalayas also literally mean the abode of snow.

Comment: Yes you are right .

Comment: @user1952500 - The clarification and additional expert opinion was required  as question  was demanding , See this - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145598.html

Comment: @user1952500 Even here we cannot find the clear mentioning the name Himalaya.

Comment: That verse refers to a previous verse which has the himavat-vindhya term. It’s again called himavat there though, not as Himalayas.

Answer (score 1):

http://meluhha.com/rv/

I searched here and neither term occurs.  recent research has shown rig vedic locales mostly correspond to present day pakistani punjab.  the word "ganga" occurs only twice.  this evidence is interpreted both ways - some say it is evidence of aryan in-migration and people like Talageri see evidence for Aryan outmigration in the same data.

Comment: there are rivers like sarasvati and sindhu are present ganga is an east river may be till that time there was no migration there which coresponds to IVC who migrated east due to shifting of river courses to east and a cultural continuity there both IVC and indo-aryan apart from invasion.

Comment: Do you believe in Aryan Invasion theory? Do you think human beings are latest?

Comment: one of the two MUST have happened either aryan outmigration or aryan immigration - the similarities between sanskrit, greek, lithuanian, avestan etc. are profound.

Comment: @SK see in mittani there were all vedic things were found scientists think they [exposed them to mittani](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitanni-Aryan) but all aryans divided from iranians so how is it possible it showed signs which were only accepted in aryans and not iranians so what you say even before that fire altars were found in [kalibangam too so....](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalibangan) we dont know what happend its **pre-historic** and all theories are **proto**.

Comment: Read above answer. It's there.